# Can't create live image for Ubuntu in windows 11

Tags: boot, usb

Recently my ubuntu 21 hdd crashed, I have dual boot and trying to create boot usb so I can reinstall, I tried all boot tool(RUFUS, etcher, unetbootin)  but non of them able to write image on usb disk, tried different usb stick as well but failed.
Looks like windows 11 is blocking something but not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Windows updates may have also done an UEFI update. UEFI updates often reset some settings back to defaults. Check UEFI settings for ACHI, Secure Boot & USB options. Often if Secure Boot on, USB options will be off (as booting USB drive is not secure).

Comment: What happens when you try to run Rufus (or other USB burning software)? Does it not detect the USB drive?

Comment: There is no such Ubuntu version as 21.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?